# Virtual functions in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual-functions

```
public class Base1
{
    public virtual void f()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base1.f()");
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Base1
{
    // Hides Base1.f() because 'override' was not specified
    public new virtual void f()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived1.f()");
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    // Overrides Derived1.f()
    public override void f()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived2.f()");

        // Call base method
        base.f();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
        Base1 ob1 = new Derived1();
        ob1.f();

        Base1 ob2 = new Derived2();
        ob2.f();

        Derived1 ob3 = new Derived2();
        ob3.f();

        Derived2 ob4 = new Derived2();
        ob4.f();
    }
}


// Calls Derived2.f() because Derived2 overrides Derived1().f()
        Derived1 ob3 = new Derived2();
        ob3.f();
```

it was expecting that the

```
Base1 ob2 = new Derived2();
ob2.f();
```

1. The derived2 function will be called but the base class function was
   called , what is  the reason for this.
2. Does .net uses vtables

Comment: Please edit your question to format it appropriately - I'd do so myself, but I can't tell what you're really trying to do at the end.

Comment: @Jon Please stick to the wedding Jon which you can surely get at the campsite!

Comment: @David: Watched the wedding a while ago. Back in the tent now.

Comment: @Jon It's still going on as far as I can tell. I actually travelled across the Atlantic to the US to escape it but it's on every single TV channel over here! The Americans just love a British royal wedding like you wouldn't believe.

Comment: @David: That's something I've been seriously wondering about. I can see why the British might be interested in it, and I can see why a British American might care about it. But I simply cannot understand why a regular old American would give a hoot about the British royal wedding. I certainly don't... For a minute or two, I was almost worried it might make me a bad person, but I got over it.

Comment: @Cody Actually, I think it's easier to see why the Americans are into it than the Brits. Americans don't have a royal family. It has mystique. The royals are just every day for us Brits.

Answer (score 6):

The method slot used by static analysis during compilation depends on the type of the **variable** (or expression), not the actual object. The variable `ob2` is typed as `Base1`, so the `Base1` method slot is used. And *then* the correct override is selected based on the typed (essentially vtable on that slot). So the base function is used.

To use the derived2 function, the *variable* (or expression) must be typed as `Derived1` or a subclass.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if the *compile-time* type of the variable you're using to call `f()` is `Base1`, it will call the base method - because nothing's actually overriding it.

If the compile-time type is `Derived1` or `Derived2`, it will call the appropriate method in either `Derived1` or `Derived2` based on the *execution-time* type of the object... because at that point the compiler will just be issuing a virtual call to `Derived1.f()`, and overriding will occur at execution time.

And yes, .NET uses vtables.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you're mixing things a bit too much.

Basically, here's what you have done:

1. You define a virtual method `f` in the base class
2. You descend from that base class, and create a *new* virtual `f` method
3. You descend from the second class, and override `f`, this overrides the one from the second class, not the one in the base class.

So, when you say:

```
Base1 b = new Derived2();
b.f();
```

then you're always (in this case) going to call the base implementation of `f`, since the overridden `f` in `Derived2` is a **different** `f` method. The name is the same, but it is still a different method.

The reason for this is that the compiler will see that the `f` you're calling is the one coming from the `Base1` class, and so it will call that.

Since no class overrides `Base1.f`, that's the one you're calling.

---

In response to the question in the comment, strictly speaking, the class will have two virtual methods, both named f.

One, however, is shadowed by the new one introduced in Derived1.

You can, inside the class, pick which to call:

```
public void MethodInDerived1()
{
    f();                            // calls Derived1.f()
    base.f();                       // calls Base1.f()
}
```

From the outside, however, you need to "pick" by casting.

In other words:

```
Derived1 d = new Derived1();
d.f();                              // calls Derived1.f()
((Base1)d).f();                     // calls Base1.f()
```

You can also observe the methods through reflection. If you execute the following code in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net), you will see that there are two methods both named `f`:

```
void Main()
{
    typeof(Derived1).GetMethods().Dump();
}

public class Base1
{
    public virtual void f()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Base1.f");
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Base1
{
    public virtual new void f()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Derived1.f");
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    public override void f()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Derived2.f");
        base.f();
    }
}
```

The output from this script, truncated (there's more info out to the right):

[image: Output from LINQPad script]

Comment: Well, strictly speaking it will have 2, but lexically you can only refer to one of them, the new one, since they have the same name. You can, however, find them using reflection. You can also call `base.f` to explicitly pick the base method.

Comment: in the vtables how this information is stored because it has 2 virtual functions